# Cannot print, echo or var_dump in Codeignitor [PHP]

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to Codeignitor, but I have some years of experience with PHP.
Although my Environment in set to development in index.php file on the root of the project,

```
if($some_stament=="true") {

$relativePath = $w->getRelativePath();
$sep = strlen($relativePath)===0?'':'/';
$command = str_replace("'", "", $previewSyncCommand[$site].' '.escapeshellarg($relativePath).$sep.$fromName.' '.$fullToPath);

var_dump($command);

$return_var=-1;
exec($command, $outputArray, $return_var);
$output = implode("\n",$outputArray);
$returnMessage = RsyncWrapper::$rsyncStatus[$return_var];

}
```

or

```
print_r($bar_variable);
echo $foo_bar;

print('example to print to screen text');
```

do not work, in fact break further execution of the if() statement, even if I don't call exit() or die();

The strangest part is that, if I remove all the dumps, prints or echos, the code run perfectly!

Does anyone have a ideia?

Comment: You'll have to share the code before and after you try to print a variable.  Do you get any error?

Comment: @sauhardnc I have added code. I can't print any values out of this var_dump, echo, print or print_r, and yes,  I am certain the code runs through the if statement.

Comment: you shouldn't start code in the index.php in root folder for Codeigniter, except if there's some default setting you need to change, you shouldn't touch this file.

Codeigniter is MVC (Model, View, Controller) framework. If you want to try create a new page, you should create Controller, Model, and View seperately. you can read it more in the website documentation page.
https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/static_pages.html

Comment: @kirb I just said my index.php file was set to development and this code is inside a controller